# python: merge list item if they are following ints but index is out of range

Tags: python, list

For example I have a list like this:

```
list = [3, 4, "-", 7, "+", 9, "/", 2]
```

In my context which is a calculator's typing, each digit arrive as a list item, but for example the `"3", "4"` should be `"34"`. I ended up with this code:=

```
for index, item in enumerate(list):
    a = index + 1
    if type(item) is int and type(list[a]) is int:
        list[index] = int(str(item) + str(list[a]))
        list.pop(a)
```

the line `list.pop(a)`isn't working because for the last item, you can't check if the next item is a int because the next item doesn't exist, it's out of range. Do you have any ideas about how to make this not happen?

Comment: Rarely a good idea to modify a list as you iterate over it. Just create a new list.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two alternative approaches:

```
def digits_to_num(digits):
    return sum(n*10**i for i, n in enumerate(reversed(digits)))
    
def _combine_ints(arr):
    digits = []
    for item in arr:
        if isinstance(item, int):
            digits.append(item)
        else:
            if digits:
                yield digits_to_num(digits)
                digits = []
            yield item
    if digits:
        yield digits_to_num(digits)

def combine_ints(arr):
    return list(_combine_ints(arr))
```

Or

```
import re

def combine_ints(arr):
    chunked = re.findall(r'\d+|[+/*-]', ''.join(map(str, arr))
    return [int(i) if i.isdecimal() else i for i in chunked]
```

In either case

```
answer = combine_ints([1, 2, 3, 4, '+', 5, 6]) # -> [1234, '+', 56]
```

If you need to handle floating point numbers these will need to be tweaked.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add another condition to your `if` statement:

```
for index, item in enumerate(list):
    a = index + 1
    if a < len(list) and type(item) is int and type(list[a]) is int :
        list[index] = int(str(item) + str(list[a]))
        list.pop(a)
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you it's working, but I figured out that if I had 3 numbers in a row, the 3rd one is not going to be merge with the 2 first. So I added a elif that checks if the previous item is a int, the code has to merge it. It works, but if it's 4 in a row... it doesn't work. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list=[]
lis = [3, 4, "-", 7,8,9,10, "+", 9, "/", 2,3]
tmp=''

 

for i in lis:
    if str(i).isdigit(): #checking whether "i" is a digit or not
        tmp+=str(i)     # If the next value is also a digit, we are combining them and storing them in a "tmp."
    else:
        new_list.append(int(tmp)) # If "i" is not a digit, append the stored "tmp" into new_list.
        new_list.append(i)
        tmp=''

print(new_list+[int(tmp)])
```

Hope this helps!